# Ensuring local caching with Ignite on YARN

Tags: apache-flink, ignite, flink-streaming

I have a stream processing application written in Flink & I want to use its internal key-value store from the state backend to compute streaming aggregates. Because I am dealing with a lot of aggregates, I would like to avoid maintaining them on-heap inside the Flink application like the memory-backed and file-backed implementations currently offer. In stead, I would like to maintain a cache of the state in Apache Ignite, which in turn could use the write-through & read-through features to provide a more reliable back-up in HBase.

Ideally, I would have a single local Ignite cache on every physical node that handles the state for all long-running Flink operators on that node. E.g. each node has a single Ignite node in an 8 GB container available, whether it is running 1 or 10 Flink operators.

The problem is that I want both Flink and Ignite to run on YARN. Through consistent partitioning, I can ensure that the data in general is sent to the correct cache, and in case of failures etc., it can be refilled from HBase. The problem I'm facing though is that Ignite seems to request containers from YARN randomly, meaning I have no guarantee that there is in fact a local cache available, even if I set the amount of Ignite nodes exactly the same as the amount of physical nodes.

Any suggestions on how to achieve a one Ignite node per physical node set up?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Did you implement already a state backend for Ignite?

Comment: No not yet. There's somewhat of a mismatch between the snapshotting logic in Flink and the write-through in Ignite. Write-through makes snapshotting a no-op because everything is automatically synced instantly, but that would break the barrier logic for exactly once semantics. Write-behind in Ignite on the other hand doesn't offer me enough control over the flushing process to do proper snapshotting either.

Comment: Why can't you use a single partitioned Ignite cache instead? It should simplify your implementation because Ignite will take care where to put and where get data. If any node leaves you won't lose any data, in case if there are backups for the cache, because all the data will be rebalanced automatically for you.

Comment: Because I want to access the data locally on each node, and Ignite's partitioning spreads the data across nodes as it sees fit without any regard for how Flink is partitioning the data across its operators. A local cache on each node, would mean that Flink's partitioning is respected as long as there are no failures. The problem I'm facing is that I cannot enforce the existence of an Ignite node on each physical node, so that I cannot guarantee the existence of a cache on each node where Flink might start an operator. I'm looking into Ignite on Slider right now to solve this problem.

Comment: How dynamic can ignite stances start? Can you simply start one as part of the Flink TaskManager or StateBackend, and it would join the grid of other instances?

Comment: Also, if you want to have your data outside the JVM heap, have a look at the recently added RocksDBStateBackend (version 1.0).

Comment: @Pieter-Jan Did you find a solution for this issue? You're right about the way Ignite currently integrates with YARN, but I think your point is valid and this could be a good addition.

Comment: No not really, currently the only implementation I have is a local mode Ignite cache. In fact, I'm not even sure of its lifespan, it's an implementation of the state backend interface

Answer (score 0):

There is a ticket created to enhance the resource allocation using YARN: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-3214. Someone in the community will puck it up and fix.